# EntityType inside CollectionType: Get current object inside query_builder

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

When using an `EntityType` inside a `CollectionType`, is it possible to access the current collection object inside the EntityType's `query_builder` function?

Main Form:

```
class UsersType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('users', CollectionType::class, array('entry_type' => UserType::class));
    }
}
```

Sub Form:

```
class UserType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('mainPost', EntityType::class, array(
                'class' => Post::class,
                'query_builder' => function (PostRepository $postRepository) {
                    return $postRepository->findPostsOfUser(); // <= Here I'd like to pass the *current* user to the repository
                },
            ))
        ;
    }
}
```

Reason: I don't want to see *all* posts at each user, but only this user's posts.

The [EntityType's docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#query-builder) say it's not possible:

> When using a callable, you will be passed the EntityRepository of the entity as the **only** argument...

Is there maybe a workaround? Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do a workaround with `FormEvents`. In the `PRE_SET_DATA` event the data for a single user entity is set. You can overwrite it like this:

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;

class UserType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('mainPost', EntityType::class, array(
                'class' => Post::class,
            ))
        ;

        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) {
            $user = $event->getData();
            $form = $event->getForm();

            $field = $form->get('mainPost');
            $options = $field->getConfig()->getOptions();
            $options['query_builder'] = function (PostRepository $postRepository) use ($user) {
                return $postRepository->findPostsOfUser($user);
            };

            $form->add($field->getName(), EntityType::class, $options);
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: This only works when I remove the line `$options = $field->getConfig()->getOptions();`. My solution: Don't add the field *before* the event listener, but only *inside* it.